# Sending the PayPal form via "GET" not "POST" by redirecting the client

Tags: php, paypal

POST is the recommended method for sending the PayPal buttons by PayPal [documentations](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#form-attributes--action-and-method). They clearly stated:

> `<FORM action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">`
>
> Important: Do not change these values. These attributes are required
>   for all payment buttons and the Cart Upload command

However in [this tutorial](https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration), the author is building the button variables on the server side then redirecting the client to PayPal, which will make the request goes for PayPal via "GET" not "POST". something *like* this

This is the form that is sent to the client (it has no PayPal variables,  just the button and optionally some variables related to my business)

```
<form class="paypal" action="/payments.php" method="post">
    <select name="product">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input name="discountCode" type="text">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

and then he built the PayPal variables on the server and redirected the client to PayPal to proceed

### payments.php

```
$paypal_email = 'user@example.com';
$return_url = 'http://example.com/payment-successful.html';
$cancel_url = 'http://example.com/payment-cancelled.html';
$notify_url = 'http://example.com/payments.php';//same file
$item_name = 'Test Item'; //build the item and amount depend on what is selected in the form
$item_amount = 5.00;

$querystring = '';
$querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";
$querystring .= "cmd=_xclick&";
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

// Redirect to paypal (will cause GET request to PayPal)
header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
exit();
```

This approach worked with me, however the POST method is the recommended one  by PayPal. I find PHP more comfortable and gives me a chance to do some work before the client goes to PayPal, like updating my back end system depending on the user choices or hiding some sensitive variables(like notify_url) from the HTML `<form>` (*the client still can see where he is being directed to though*).

**Is it reliable and supported to build the PayPal variables at the server side then redirecting the client to PayPal with a GET request ?**

Comment: You can easily redirect with a post form data, by creating a hidden form and submitting it with javascript.

Comment: Do you mean hidden `<input>` 's in a regular form  with no java script involving like `<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">       <input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@example.com">` ?

Comment: And with an added `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();</script>` just after the `</form>`, instead of `header("Location: ...");`. So you basically echo a normal form with all hidden fields and automatically submit it.

Comment: I need to update the `<form>` products prices depend on the used discount codes and update the used discount codes state in my back end database before the user goes to PayPal website. My second option will be as you said using java script like in here [https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1512&expand=true&locale=en_US](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1512&expand=true&locale=en_US) . But I'm going to use this java script option if this PHP work is not recommended and not reliable.

Comment: @DainisAbols Ohh , yes I just got it!! . yes that is a cleaver solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not saying that this is the best option, but to create a post form, you can edit your **payments.php** as follows:

```
<?php

$paypal_email = 'user@example.com';
$return_url   = 'http://example.com/payment-successful.html';
$cancel_url   = 'http://example.com/payment-cancelled.html';
$notify_url   = 'http://example.com/payments.php';//same file
$item_name    = 'Test Item'; //build the item and amount depend on what is selected in the form
$item_amount  = 5.00;

$querystring = [
    'business'      => urlencode($paypal_email),
    'cmd'           => '_xclick',
    'item_name'     => urlencode($item_name),
    'amount'        => urlencode($item_amount),
    'return'        => urlencode(stripslashes($return_url)),
    'cancel_return' => urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url)),
    'notify_url'    => urlencode($notify_url),
];

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
        <?php
        foreach ($querystring as $a => $b) {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."' />";
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

POST is recommended as it is possible to exceed the maximum URL length limit using the GET method, resulting in the following error on PayPal:

> HTTP 414 URI Too Long

This size soon adds up when you start including multiple products, names, prices, server tokens, address etc. Personally I have seen this limit exceeded on occasions with a single product and minimal data, so it is safer for cross-browser compatibility purposes to use POST.

Comment: Thank you for the note, yes GET has maximum length. I was asking about if sending the variables as GET variables documented by PayPal or supported or not. I'm doing it as @Peon suggested now for 2 years and his method works fine with me, thank you for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: @Accountantم Yes I thought I'd just add clarity to the post as to why GET is not recommend (although is accepted). Just like Peon suggests in his answer and proven by yourself, switching to POST is safer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it doesn't really matter whether you use the autosubmit javascript or a header and get fields to paypal.  What does matter is that what you send to paypal should NOT be in hidden fields with a form saying "click to pay now" ie not autosubmitted else a user can read those hidden fields in the browsers debug mode.  I pass those coded variables to a separate send page (B) as Session variables from page (A), uncode the in (B), generate a pass through token to paypal and do a lot of redundant checking on (B), eg page aborts if not come from (A), all the SESSION variables there and matching their uncoded counterparts.  The pass through generated token field sent to paypal is returned, so can be compared with its coded session counterpart to verify paypal, although you can curl to paypal to check its legit.  You have to be lightning quick to stop the browser on (B) alone and you could theoretically read both post and get there, but not waiting for user input is a huge deterrent security wise, and you'd have to duplicate a lot of redundant checking variables.

Comment: If I understand it right, do you mean that you don't want to set hidden fields data in the form submitted to PayPal, but you want to put them in a form submitted to your page (B) ? and depend on the fact the user will not be fast enough to stop the browser before redirecting and see those hidden fields ? If this is the case, then the user don't need to stop the browser, he can record the network traffic and see them hours later, or use a custom bot that reads those values. Can you please provide a simple code example to demonstrate your idea ?